# Is Univariate comparison of 10 subjects using log rank test in Kaplan Meier survival is statistically sound?

Tags: survival, logrank-test

I have 10 subjects and want to analyse the predictors of overall survival and progression free survival using log rank test .
 Will conducting log rank test on such a small sample size will be statistically sound ?
can we plot a overall survival curve  for entire 10 subjects?

what should be the minimum sample size for using Kaplan meier plots and log rank tests ?